# actionscript 2.0 referencing main timeline form movie clip

Tags: actionscript-2

Trying to edit as 2 file and stuck on how to tell a movie clip to gotoAndPlay the main time line.

The animation contains several tweens and I need to add a temporary tween.
I created a movie clip with tween.
Once the it gets to the Movie Clip(frame 10), I inserted the stop command so the the movieclip can run its tween. 
The problem I am having is how to tell flash to resume the animation from frame 11.

I put
parent.gotoAndPlay(11);

but doesn't work...

Thanks,
Rexon

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a _global ref to the movie you'd like to control.
(I try to avoid using _global, but sometimes ...)

The real problem is why "parent" doesn't reference the object you expect. You could try to debug and see what the current tree is.

Another way is to pass the ref to the parent to the "to-be-caller" on creation.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `_parent` instead of `parent`.

And if that doesn't work try to `trace(_parent`) like Milo suggested. That should give you the path to your the clips parent, and you should be able to count how many `_parent._parent` you should use to hit the right clip.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this as well, but it did not work:

```
parent.gotoAndPlay(11);
```

So instead try to use the keyword `_root`:

```
_root.gotoAndPlay(11);
```

This worked for me.